# AngularJS 1.x: Click radio button and sibling input element focuses

Tags: angularjs, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a form in Angular 1.5 (with Bootstrap) and I want the following functionality:

When the user clicks the radio button, I want it to focus on the input text element in the radio-group and vice versa (i.e. the user clicks the input text element and radio button is checked).

I was thinking I will need to use either ng-click or ng-change and write a function. But I've been stumped.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="radio-group">
    <input type="radio"
           name="phone"
           ng-model="contactMethod"
           value="phone"/>

    <label for="phoneNumber" class="radio-inline">Phone</label>

    <input type="text"
           id="phoneNumber"
           name="phoneNumberInput"
           ui-mask="(999) 999-9999"
           ng-model="phoneNum"
           class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

EDIT: I received a very helpful answer that works great for this specific case (see below). But I would also like to know if there a way to generalize the solution so that it will work for multiple radio-button groups.

Comment: So you don't want it to actually focus both ways. If the user clicks the radio button, you want the cursor (focus) on the input text field. If the user clicks the text field, you want the radio button to select. But you don't want it to focus on the radio button (that would be annoying, the cursor would leave the text field). 

I'll try a quick sample and see if I can get it working. Not going to bother with angular though this should just be straight html/js. Basic click events and focus setting should do the trick.

Comment: Exactly. I'm relatively new to Angular, so I didn't know if there was a specific "Angular" way to do it using something like $watch for example.

Answer (score 1):

This does it, click the text field and the RB selects (but the cursor stays in the text field), click the RB and the RB selects and the cursor goes into the text field.

You can also do this with the value of ng-model and so on, but meh. This is the bare metal idea. You may want to add a check to short circuit it if the RB is already selected and so on.

```
<script>
function onElemClick(elem) {
  if ( elem.id === 'phone_rb' ) {
    document.getElementById('phoneNumber').focus();
  } else if ( elem.id === 'phoneNumber' ) {
    document.getElementById('phone_rb').checked = 'checked';
  }
}
</script>

<div class="radio-group">
    <input type="radio"
           id="phone_rb"
           name="phone"
           onclick="onElemClick(this)"
           value="phone"/>

    <label for="phoneNumber">Phone</label>

    <input type="text"
           id="phoneNumber"
           name="phoneNumberInput"
           onclick="onElemClick(this)"
           ui-mask="(999) 999-9999"/>
</div>
```

Comment: OK. So what if I want to abstract this up one level (i.e. I want it to be general to all radio-groups in the app, such as email, etc)?

This example is specific to this particular situation

Comment: I actually think I may have answer to my previous comment. But I'd like to see what you think too.

Comment: Well, that's what you asked for. But then you'd either want to just put the function on some sort of utils file, or more "angular-ish", create a radio button directive that you can feed text field ids. 

So your RB markup would look like:

<div my-rb-directive textfieldid="the_text_field_you_want_paired" />

IDS have to be unique, so that's fine. In the rb directive, when the wrapped HTML RB is clicked, you'd just do a document.select for the ID you fed in and put the focus on it, and vice versa.

Note you could also do this with some fancy CSS I think. That's not my thing though.

Comment: Thank you! I think writing a directive would be overkill because this scenario occurs only a few times in the app. But this is great to know

Comment: In angular, writing a directive is never overkill. It's one of the hells of angular (I assume you are using 1.x). Everything is so much boilerplate, but you really shouldn't try to work around it or the "it should be an angular directive" chorus WILL FIND YOU.

Comment: OK. Well now I guess I might have to write a directive to get this functionality.

Also, I edited my original to apply to more general situations. At this point, I think a plain JS solution might be just fine.